# JQuery-UI containment: 'parent' does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, containment

As you see here, div with the class .foo is draggable and has containment: 'parent' option, so it must stay in the bounds of its parent div, which is mainDiv, but it does not. Why is that?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#deviceName li').draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: 'invalid'
    });
    $('#interface li').draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: 'invalid'
    });
    $('#display li').draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: 'invalid'
    });
    $('#output li').draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: 'invalid'
    });
    $('.foo').each(function(){
        $(this).draggable({
            containment: $(this).parent()
        });
    });
    $('#mainDiv').droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            if(ui.draggable.hasClass('foo')){
                
            }
            else {
                var title = ui.draggable.text().trim();
                var item = $('<div class="foo">').append('<table class="elementTable"><tr><th class="thClass">' + title + '</th></tr></table>');
                item.draggable();
                $(this).append(item);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #2c2c2c;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#2c2c2c), color-stop(37%,#3d3d3d), color-stop(66%,#353535), color-stop(66%,#353535), color-stop(100%,#131313));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%,#3d3d3d 37%,#353535 66%,#353535 66%,#131313 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%,#3d3d3d 37%,#353535 66%,#353535 66%,#131313 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%,#3d3d3d 37%,#353535 66%,#353535 66%,#131313 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c2c2c 0%,#3d3d3d 37%,#353535 66%,#353535 66%,#131313 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c2c2c', endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=1 );
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#leftDiv{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16%;
    min-height: 100%;
    border-right: 3px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
#mainDiv{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 64%;
    min-height: 100%;
    border-right: 3px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
#rightDiv{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
.foo{
    max-width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.foo table{
    width: 100%;
}
.thClass{
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial; color: white;">
    <div id="leftDiv">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>Device Name
                <ul id="deviceName">
                    <li>
                      item 1
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Interface
                <ul id="interface">
                    <li>
                      item 2
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Display
                <ul id="display">
                    <li>
                      item 3
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Output
                <ul id="output">
                    <li>
                      item 4
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="mainDiv">
    
    </div>
    <div id="rightDiv">
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you see here, div with the class .foo is draggable and has containment: 'parent' option, so it must stay in the bounds of its parent div, which is mainDiv, but it does not. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following:

```
$('.foo').each(function(){
    $(this).draggable({
        containment: $(this).parent()
    });
});
```

Reason is that the containment option can also be a jquery selector or an actual element.

You can try it in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MAEvS/925/)

```
$('.foo').each(function() {
  $(this).draggable({
    containment: $(this).parent()
  });
});
```

The above code is called before the elements was created. So wrap them in a function can call it when a new object is created.

```
function foo(){
  $('.foo').each(function() {
    $(this).draggable({
      containment: $(this).parent()
    });
  });
}
```

**Working snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#deviceName li').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
  });
  $('#interface li').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
  });
  $('#display li').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
  });
  $('#output li').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
  });
function foo(){
  $('.foo').each(function() {
    $(this).draggable({
      containment: $(this).parent()
    });
  });
}
  $('#mainDiv').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.draggable.hasClass('foo')) {

      } else {
        var title = ui.draggable.text().trim();
        var item = $('<div class="foo">').append('<table class="elementTable"><tr><th class="thClass">' + title + '</th></tr></table>');
        item.draggable();
        $(this).append(item);
        foo()
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2c2c2c;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #2c2c2c), color-stop(37%, #3d3d3d), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(100%, #131313));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c2c2c', endColorstr='#131313', GradientType=1);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#leftDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16%;
  min-height: 100%;
  border-right: 3px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

#mainDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 64%;
  min-height: 100%;
  border-right: 3px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

#rightDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.foo {
  max-width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.foo table {
  width: 100%;
}

.thClass {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="font-family: Arial; color: white;">
  <div id="leftDiv">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li>Device Name
        <ul id="deviceName">
          <li>
            item 1
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Interface
        <ul id="interface">
          <li>
            item 2
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Display
        <ul id="display">
          <li>
            item 3
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Output
        <ul id="output">
          <li>
            item 4
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="mainDiv">

  </div>
  <div id="rightDiv">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Does the same. I have tried to do it like that before. Is there any styling in css that could cause problems with containment? Or maybe my function while dropping is affecting it.

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze how can i know without seeing your style?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I have added my styling as well to the question.

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze you style don't create any problems for me, i suggest you create a snippet that shows the problem

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Snippet is added

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze Try run the snippet in my answer

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen It works, but what was the problem?

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze check the explanation